# SlideToggle list to show only part of list when closed

Tags: jquery, html

I have a long list of items
I want to show only part of it by default
And show all items on button click

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alikey/1ts8m83d/2/), but how to animate it with jQuery slideToggle():

HTML:

```
<ul class="faded part">
  <li>List item</li>    
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<button class="expand">Open</button>
```

CSS:

```
.part li:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  display: inherit !important;
}    
.part li {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expand").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "Close") {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("part");
      $(this).text("Close");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("part");
      $(this).text("Open");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For animate the li use SlideUp SlideDown function.

Check this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expand").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "Close") {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").find("li:nth-child(3)").nextAll().slideDown(function(){
       });
      $(this).text("Close");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").find("li:nth-child(3)").nextAll().slideUp(function(){
    });
      $(this).text("Open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inherit;
}

.part li:nth-of-type(1n+4) {display: none;} {
  display:none;
}


.faded {
  position: relative;
}

.faded:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="part">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<button class="expand">Open</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. But how to make it slide down from and up to 3rd line with smooth sliding without this "jumping" effect?

Comment: @aleebek I've updated the snippet. Please re run this snippet for check that this will give you the same output as you want or not

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

check [this](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php) link for more information.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".expand").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "Close") {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("closed");
      $(this).text("Close");
      
    } else {
      $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("closed");
      $(this).text("Open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inherit;
}

.slider.closed {
 max-height: 20px;
}

.slider {
 overflow-y: hidden;
 max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height */

 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider closed">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<button class="expand">Open</button>
```